# fscanf failing in this C code

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

So being a new intern, I need to fix a lot of dirty code that some of these people wrote. Heres a snippet and I'm having a little issue figuring out what is the precise issue:

```
for (i=0; i<TOOL_LIMIT; i++)
        {
                if ( 0 >= fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n",coreData[i][0],\
coreData[i][1],coreData[i][2],coreData[i][3],coreData[i][4],coreData[i][5], coreData[i][6]))
                {
                        break;
                }
                totalCases++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
```

Basically, fp is opened to some file that has the following regex pattern:

```
data11 data12 data13 data14...data17
data21 data22 data23 data24...data27
...
```

I feel like this code isn't working the way it's intended too. Basically, its suppose to read each line of the file, and fill in the array coreData as shown. I don't think fscanf works like it's being shown here, but I could be wrong.
Is this code working as it should? I haven't done file io with c in a while.

Edit;;
Sorry, should give a brief overview of failure.
Basically, the C-script is a cgi script that takes in some inputs (files that have errors) and matches those files to the data in the file opened by fp (call it 'fp_file'), and generates an html table. If the file with the error shows up in the fp_file, then it prints some extra information (like data12 etc), otherwise it leaves the entry in that table blank.
Example
File f01 was found to have an error
we now check fp for 'f01', if it exists, we show some more information about that file (author, etc).

What I am seeing is that only one file is being matched up correctly (the first line of fp). Other than that, a blank space is in place for the rest of the error files.

Comment: what is the type of `coreData`? What is the return value from `fscanf`? What is the value of the `coreData` variables after the call to `fscanf`? It would help if you could provide a **small**, **complete** test case -- see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I made an edit about how it's failing. And I'm using a sample file as a test. I have a feeling that it's not getting past the first line

Comment: You debug by feelings?  Are you a Jedi?  Or an Empath?

Comment: Lol, I did some debugging. I replaced the first line with a different line, and the original file that was matched correctly wasn't being matched any longer. I'm still debugging as we speak. Is there a better way to read the file line by line?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using fgets to read an entire line of the file, then sscanf to read from the single line into individual fields.

Answer (score 1):

This code reads groups of six words, separated by whitespace, and store them in the coreData array.

I think it works as long as input lines have six words separated by whitespace. You could strengthen the condition slightly, and break from the loop as soon as fscanf returns a value different from 6 (fscanf returns the number of elements successfully read).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake typing it, the file has exactly 7 words per line, and the fscanf now reflects that.